# Tkinter entry for USB device checker

Tags: python, tkinter, usb, tkinter-entry

I have a function that checks if a USB device is there and returns the result on its own, and a Tkinter GUI that takes the inputs for this function.
The function works just fine alone, but never with the Tkinter GUI!(even when i leave the entry empty so the function takes the default variables)

i tried changing the entry forms into int or float but it did not work

```
def check_USB(vid=0x1447,pid=0x8092):#pings usb device
 logger.debug('checking USB Connection')
 dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=vid, idProduct= pid)
 if dev is None:
    logger.debug ('ALERT our USB device is NOT connected')
 else:
    logger.debug('our USB device is connected') 

 entry_VID = Entry(second_frame, bg="white")
 entry_VID.grid(row=8,column=1,padx=0,pady=5)
 entry_PID = Entry(second_frame, bg="white")
 entry_PID.grid(row=10,column=1,padx=0,pady=5)

 check_USB(vid=int( entry_VID.get() ),pid=int( entry_PID.get() ) )
```

i tried this same process with a function that pings an ip address (but the ip address taken entry is a string) and it works perfectly, however with this script i get always that the device is not connected.

Error: (0x1447 was my input for vid and 0x8092 for pid)

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10:'0x1447'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under your current setup, `check_USB(vid=entry_VID.get(),pid=entry_PID.get())` is run immediately. You need to wait for user to fill up the entries. It can be something like this:

```
entry_VID = Entry(second_frame, bg="white")
entry_VID.grid(row=8,column=1,padx=0,pady=5)
entry_PID = Entry(second_frame, bg="white")
entry_PID.grid(row=10,column=1,padx=0,pady=5)

def usb_func():  
    check_USB(vid=int(entry_VID.get(),16),
              pid=int(entry_PID.get(),16))

Button(second_frame,text="Click",command=usb_func).grid(row=11,column=1)
```

You can then execute the function only when the user press the button, or even do some validation to check if the user entered correct numbers in the entries if needed.

Comment: i already had a button, sorry i forgot to show.
now i added a line to print the vid and pid values if the device is not connected.
To my surprise, eventhough it is getting the vid and pid values right, it always shows that the device is not connected !
i am sure the hardware setup is right

Comment: Keep in mind that `entry.get()` returns a string. Is your `check_usb` function expecting `int` as input parameters?

Comment: when i try converting to int or float with a code running the GUI i get the error : 
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0x1447'
when i try running it without the GUI it runs just fine...

Comment: I think you should edit your question, show the dummy data you input, how you convert to int and full traceback of the error so we can see.

Comment: Now it is much clearer. 0x1447 is a hex string, and so when you cast it into `int` you need to specify it by `int(entry_VID.get(),16)`.